# How to submit a Page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I need submit a page after some validation is done. I never used jQuery before, any idea how to do it?
Script come from this tutorial http://webcloud.se/log/Form-validation-with-jQuery-from-scratch/

```
<form method="post" action="/contact-process" id="demo-form">

    <script>
        var demoForm = $("#demo-form");
        demoForm.validation();
        demoForm.submit(function (e) {

            $("#valid-form").remove();
            if (demoForm.validate()) {
                demoForm.append("<strong id='valid-form'>Form is valid!</strong>");
            // Here submit the page

            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: document.name_of_the_form.submit

Comment: If you want the page to just submit normally and page refresh after validation, just put the `e.preventDefault()` in an `} else {` after that `if`.

Comment: Is the element with the id `valid-form`, a `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your handler to only prevent default if the form is invalid:

```
demoForm.submit(function (e) {
    $("#valid-form").remove();
    if (demoForm.validate()) {
        demoForm.append("<strong id='valid-form'>Form is valid!</strong>");
    }
    else
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: While InvisibleBacon has answered your question correctly, it doesn't address style issues, regarding how and where you use jquery calls.  Most importantly, wrapping everything in $(document).ready() so that nothing can fire that depends on a DOM element that hasn't finished loading yet.  Also, if all you want to do is stop submission if the form is invalid, then you simply need an if statement that does that when the value is false, no need for if/else at all.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're handling the form's `submit` event, you only need to call `preventDefault()` if it is invalid:

```
demoForm.submit(function(e) {
    $("#valid-form").remove();
    if (demoForm.validate()) {
        demoForm.append("<strong id='valid-form'>Form is valid!</strong>");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting your script code to only prevent the submit if validation fails.  For example the following code (since you only provided a snippet, I just created a basic page that does essentially what you want, you'll have to adjust your code as needed)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var valid = true;
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            if (!valid) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="anotherpage.htm">
    <input type="text" value="hello"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
```

1. Calling .preventDefault (side note: you can also return false) stops the submit from actually taking place. If the form is valid, it skips the if statement and continues with the submit.
2. You should place your jquery code inside $(document).ready(function() {}); because you don't want anything to fire before the DOM is fully loaded.
3. Generally, you should place your script tag in the HEAD element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
$("#valid-form").submit();
```

But...in your code your removing the form, so there's nothing to submit. Maybe you can use hide() instead of remove().

Comment: I get this error: Line: 42
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method source code for js here any ideas? http://webcloud.se/log/Form-validation-with-jQuery-from-scratch/jquery.validation.js

Comment: Well yeah, of course that is because you removed the form first!

Comment: strange thing, I receive an error Error: Object doesn't support this property or method but after the page can been submitted erro is in  jqery.min.js

Comment: If you try to figure out which object the message is about...you should be on the roll again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`$("#valid-form").submit();`

Comment: I tried but i get an error:
 Object doesn't support this property or method source code for js here any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#valid-form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If form is valid just `return true` else `return false` it will stop the form to submit.

```
    demoForm.submit(function (e) {

        $("#valid-form").remove();
        if (demoForm.validate()) {
            demoForm.append("<strong id='valid-form'>Form is valid!</strong>");

            return true;            

        }
        return false;
    });
```